# Dusk vs. Twilight

Tags: synonyms

I'm really confused about the correct usage of *dusk* and *twilight.* Can we use them to describe the time before night falls or day breaks?

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary entries for these words?

Answer (score 18):

This is actually an interesting question, since they aren't quite synonyms as one might imagine. Here's what a bit of research produced:

The casual difference in definition is as follows (via Wikipedia):

Twilight:

> Twilight is the illumination of the Earth's lower atmosphere when the Sun itself is not directly visible because it is below the horizon.

Dusk:

> Dusk is the darkest stage of twilight in the evening.

---

However, there are 3 more rigorously defined types of twilight and dusk — *civil*, *nautical*, and *astronomical*. Here are the distinctions (via [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/different-types-twilight.html)):

*Civil Twilight*:

> Civil twilight occurs when the Sun is less than 6 degrees below the horizon. In the morning, civil twilight begins when the Sun is 6 degrees below the horizon and ends at sunrise. In the evening, it begins at sunset and ends when the Sun reaches 6 degrees below the horizon.

*Civil Dusk*:

> Civil dusk is the moment when the geometrical center of the Sun is 6 degrees below the horizon in the evening.

---

*Nautical Twilight*:

> Nautical twilight occurs when the geometrical center of the Sun is between 6 degrees and 12 degrees below the horizon. This twilight period is less bright than civil twilight and artificial light is generally required for outdoor activities.

*Nautical Dusk*:

> Nautical dusk occurs when the Sun goes 12 degrees below the horizon in the evening.

---

*Astronomical Twilight*:

> Astronomical twilight occurs when the Sun is between 12 degrees and 18 degrees below the horizon.

*Astronomical Dusk*:

> Astronomical dusk is the instant when the geographical center of the Sun is at 18 degrees below the horizon. After this point, the sky is no longer illuminated.

Comment: Nick: that means twilight comes first and dusk second?

Comment: Yes- at night, twilight is a period that dusk comes at the end of.

Comment: In common usage (at least in American English), they seem to be completely interchangeable (along with *sunset*), except for poetic differences. By "poetic", I mean that *dusk* has possibly more sinister connotations than *twilight*, and of course there are commonly used phrases like "dawn 'til dusk" where one would not be swapped for the other.

Comment: I think of dusk as relating to a stage of the sunset process, while twilight describes the light in the sky. For example in a very northerly (or southerly) place, you might have days or weeks of twilight, but dusk would only happen once (or not at all).

Answer (score 6):

To add to @Nick's answer **dusk = evening** and **twilight = morning or evening** although [first light](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/first+light) and [dawn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dawn) are more often used when referring to the morning.

Comment: Also: daybreak.